# JSTL forEach doesn't loop

Tags: java, foreach, jstl

I have strange problem with forEach in jstl. Here is my code

```
<c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="5">
    Item <c:out value="${i}"/><p>

</c:forEach>
```

As you can see, it should print:  Item 1, Item 2, Item 3, Item 4, Item 5

But all what I get is - "Item" . Only one string without iterating variable value. I'm using Apache Tomcat 8 as server, and Intelij Idea as IDE.

Are any ideas?

Comment: check if your code is between <body> your code ...</body>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- Check if you added core taglib at the top of the page

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

2- Check if you added [JSTL jar](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) to webapp

Comment: It's a right answer. Thank you.

Comment: @snith mark this answer as accepted to help others who has the same problem to solve it